# How to store multiple results returned from a row calculation in different new columns?

Tags: dolphindb

I want to iterate through each row of a table, and generate new columns storing the calculation results of original fields in each row.

For example, I get a table *inputTable* containing 4 columns: type, col1, col2, and col3. I want to perform such calculations:

If `type`=`a, then calculate the minimum and maximum values of col1~col3, and return the values in two new columns.

If `type`=`b, then calculate the average value and standard deviation of col1~col3, and return the values in two new columns.

Finally, I wish to store the returned values in newCol1 (containing the minimum value or the average value), newCol2 (containing maximum value or standard deviation), and return a new table *outputTable*.

Answer (score 1):

I think you do not need to actually *iterate* the table. You can do your calculation for different types separately:

```
select rowMin(col1, col2, col3) as newCol1, rowMax(col1, col2, col3) as newCol2 from t where type = "a"
select rowAvg(col1, col2, col3) as newCol1, rowStd(col1, col2, col3) as newCol2 from t where type = "b"
```

Or in one line:

```
select iif(
  type == "a",
  rowMin(col1, col2, col3),
  rowAvg(col1, col2, col3)
) as newCol1, iif(
  type == "a",
  rowMax(col1, col2, col3),
  rowStd(col1, col2, col3)
) as newCol2 from t
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two methods to solve your problems:

Method 1: `case` statement (supported since version 1.30.21/2.00.9)

```
select case when symbol=`a then rowMin(price1, price2, price3)  else rowAvg(price1, price2, price3) end as col1, case when symbol=`a then rowMax(price1, price2, price3) else rowStd(price1, price2, price3) end as col2, * from t
```

Method 2: `iif` function

```
select iif(symbol==`a, rowMin(price1, price2, price3), rowAvg(price1, price2, price3)) as col1, iif(symbol==`a, rowMax(price1, price2, price3), rowStd(price1, price2, price3)) as col2 from t
```